# Intellij autocompletion distinct declared and inherited methods

Tags: intellij-idea, autocomplete

In autocompletion is there a way to distinguish declared and inherited methods?

For example, I declare `ArrayList list = new ArrayList();`

In autocompletion how can I see, which methods belongs to ArrayList, which to AbstractList, which to Object etc.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you invoke completion in `list.<caret>` position, the methods declared in `ArrayList` class should be shown in bold.
[image]

Comment: I you sure? I cant see this working by default for me.

Comment: Yes, I've attached a screenshot. It might be that your editor font's bold style doesn't differ much from the plain style. Please also note that all methods defined in ArrayList are displayed in bold, even if they implement some supertype methods.

Comment: Yeah, seems to be that, thanks. But in dark theme bold font is not so obvious, unfortunately.

Comment: Wow, I didnt realize being cool with my dark theme was preventing me from seeing bold font in the list. Thanks for the heads-up!

Answer (score 0):

Hope it's better now. I have pushed the fix in IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2 [image: Will be available in 2017.2]

Comment: Yeah, that would be much better. Waiting for Android Studio to implement this. Thanks.